# Alt+Left/Right behaving strangely Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm told that `Alt+Left/Right` should navigate between the open tabs in Android Studio, but for some reason I get this kind of behavior when I do multiple tab movements:

[image]

After the 3rd/4th (not sure) use of the shortcut the focus goes away from the editor window to the tool window on the left and then the shortcut seems to switch between tabs in there.

---

I'm using Android Studio 3.4.2, Win 10.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with terminology related to Android Studio's UI, so sorry for the lack of explanation

Comment: It seems like you're using Linux (or Windows?), so this may be an OS thing that is capturing the focus. You open (or focus) that panel, by pressing `alt + 1`, and you can always go back to your editor by using `control + tab` or `control + e` (recent files).

Comment: Sorry should've specified - windows

Comment: `Alt + 1` opens/focuses the Project tool window, but that's not what I'm after.

I just want a quick way of switching between tabs while coding. `Ctrl + Tab` and then using `Up` and `Down` to navigate (while still holding `Ctrl`) kind of works, but is a bit of a hassle.